# telerik grid with gridclientselectcolumn and hierarchy select doesn't mark selected marks on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have telerik grid with hierarchy and  gridclientselectcolumn on the external table on my aspx page.

```
  <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgUsersInSessions" ShowStatusBar="true" OnNeedDataSource="OnNeedDataSourceForGrid" OnDetailTableDataBind="OnDetailTableDateBind" OnItemDataBound="OnAnswerItemBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10"
                    AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="False" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None">
                    <ClientSettings AllowExpandCollapse="True">
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                        <ClientEvents OnHierarchyExpanding="RowExpanded" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
                    <MasterTableView EnableHierarchyExpandAll="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" ClientIDMode="Static" HierarchyLoadMode="Conditional">
                        <DetailTables>
                            <telerik:GridTableView HierarchyLoadMode="Conditional" EnableHierarchyExpandAll="true" Width="100%" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ShowHeader="False">
                                    <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="userQuestion">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventId").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>                                     
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </telerik:GridTableView>
                            </DetailTables>
                        <Columns>  
                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SessionUserId" Display="False" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="SessionUserId" DataType="System.Int32">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                         </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Also I have a LinkButton

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="OnApproveButtonClick"/>
```

In the event handler I try to get selected items count  as

```
rgUsersInSessions.SelectedItems.Count
```

But I get 0 when I checked several items at UI page.

When I try to check the select all checkbox (in the header of grid), I get js error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get_element' of null
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid._selectAllRows
>   onclick

Any ideas, how to get the selected items at server side using gridclientselectcolumn ?